# How to set different Value for each loop in IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setValue for each cell separately while loop is running.

```
for (var i = 5; i <= lastRow; i++) { // Start from row 5

  var pos = sheet.getRange([i], 1); // 1 == column A, A=1,B=2,C=3 etc. 
  var posValue = (pos.isPartOfMerge() ? pos.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1, 1) : pos).getValue(); // get value of marged cell
  var animalColor = sheet.getRange([i], 9); // 9 == column I

  if (posValue == 'Cat') {
    animalColor.setValue('brown');
  } else if (posValue == 'Dog') {
    animalColor.setValue('black');
  } else if {
    animalColor.setValue('none');
  }
}
```

I want to go from this:

[image: This is what I get right now]

To this:

[image: This is what I want to get]

I tried to write additional IF statements but that just felt dumb and code will get heavier.

Comment: `} else if {` wrong syntax. Either add a condition for the `if` or just have `} else {` if it's supposed to not have condition to it.

Comment: What is the logic for the desired result? I can see that you don't want the same color for all rows of an animal. But where does the actual order come from?

Comment: @VLAZ please see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmMiT.png with desired result. I can't get that result with just `} else {`

Comment: @Barmar I would like script to read value in merged cell (example "Dog") and then next to merged cells script sets desired values. Because of loop it only sets one value for all cells.

Comment: The last condition should probably be `else if (posValue == 'Bird')`

Comment: But where do the desired values come from? Why is dog `white-black-red-grey` while Cat is `brown-black-white-gray`?

Comment: @Barmar I would like to set values manually in code like I did with one color `animalColor.setValue('brown');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of colors for each animal. Then you can get the next value from the appropriate animal's array.

```js
const colors = {
  Dog: {
    colors: ['white', 'black', 'red', 'grey'],
    index: 0
  },
  Cat: {
    colors: ['brown', 'black', 'white', 'gray'],
    index: 0
  },
  Bird: {
    colors: ['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'purple'],
    index: 0
  }
};

for (var i = 5; i <= lastRow; i++) { // Start from row 5

  var pos = sheet.getRange([i], 1); // 1 == column A, A=1,B=2,C=3 etc. 
  var posValue = (pos.isPartOfMerge() ? pos.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1, 1) : pos).getValue(); // get value of marged cell
  var animalColor = sheet.getRange([i], 9); // 9 == column I
  if (posValue in colors) {
    animalColor.setValue(colors[posValue].colors[colors[posValue].index++]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Only missing `,` after second array and there is typo in `color[colors[posValue].index++]);` should be `colors[colors[posValue].index++]);`

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate solution

You can use the `includes`,`map` and `setValues` methods in getting the desired output. You may use the script below as a guide.

### Script:

```
const colors = {
    "Cat": ["brown", "black", "white", "gray"],
    "Dog": ["white", "black", "red", "gray"],
    "Bird": ["yellow", "red", "blue", "purple"]
  };

function transformTable() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // Get the active sheet
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A"); // Get the range of the data
  var values = range.getValues().flat().filter(x => x); // Get the values of the data
  var animalsInData = Object.keys(colors);
  var output = [];

  values.map(x => (animalsInData.includes(x))? colors[x].map(y=>output.push([y])) : output.push([""]));
  sheet.getRange(1,3,output.length,1).setValues(output); // edit the range accordingly 
}
```

### Output:

[image]

Please note that I have added `snake` as a test case to see if the script will run even if there is an additional animal outside the `colors` object.

### References:

[setValues method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

[JavaScript Array map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

[JavaScript String includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)